# How to determine where GRUB really is

Tags: dual-boot, grub2

I've seen questions like this answered for simpler situations, but from what I've seen my situation is extreme.  I don't just have Linux and Windows on the same system, I have Windows, Fedora Linux, and Xubuntu, and several different releases of each Linux.  Now the problem is that I'm about to abandon some of the old (very old) Linux installs to free up some disk space and I don't want to clobber Grub in the process.  And I don't remember how it was set up on each of my 5 desktop and 2 laptop machines, so one answer won't do: I need an answer for each machine I'm about to do this on.

BTW, the machines are all different, having been acquired at different times.  Three were donations.  The oldest was my PhD graduation present to myself.   The biggest has dual 16-core Xeons running in 256GB of ram (more or less a retirement present to myself).  All are forming a Beowulf cluster for hobby projects that require a lot of computational horespower.

Anyway, the problem is knowing which partition's /etc/default/grub and /boot/grub are actually involved in booting the machine.  I'm worried because on the machine I'm about to reconfigure, the default OS is in one of the partitions I want to remove -- it was a test of concept for fixing a problem I was having, and installing a new Linux on it made it take over control of Grub (I think).

Anyway, I'm open to short- or long- term solutions.  I could reorganize to avoid this problem in the future if anyone can tell me how best to do that.

Or I would settle for being able to tell for certain what bits are in use by Grub and how to move that if necessary.

The software resides mainly on two drives: /dev/sda is devoted to Windows 10, and at least originally had just the Windows loader; it may have Grub now.  All Linux OS partitions are on /dev/sdb.  Other partitions contain /tmp, projects, and a RAID-5 array and are shared among all the Linux OSes.  On a fresh boot drives through /dev/sdf are populated.

So how do I safely reformat old partitions?

Comment: Grub is always in the ESP (EFI System Partition) in any system newer than 2012 properly installed in UEFI mode or at the MBR of the boot drive in older BIOS systems. In order to do what you want you need to assure the Grub from the distro you want to keep in in control of the boot process.

Comment: The stub file .../EFI/ubuntu/grub.cfg will have a UUID for the root, pretty clearly indication where it came from.

Comment: @ubfan1 I can't find a path like  .../EFI/ubuntu/grub.cfg so i can't follow your hint.

Comment: The EFI partition filesystem starts with EFI, so wherever you mount it is the ... Typically a running system mounts it at /boot/efi, so in that case, /boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu/grub.cfg.  If you run an install media and mount it at /mnt, it would be /mnt/EFI/ubuntu/grub.cfg

Comment: Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the Bootinfo summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed.Lets see details, use ppa version with your USB installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not Boot-Repair ISO
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair            
https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/  I periodically run this report just to document my system's configuration & include it in my backups.

Comment: @ubfan1 these systems do not use EFI, although they (mostly) have GPT partitions.  And I don't understand how an install medium would help me find the grub that the live system uses.

Comment: @oldfred You've lost me.  What pastebin link?  What auto fix?  I'm feeling stupid/uninformed right now.

Comment: Aha, a legacy system boot's binary blobs outside of any filesystem, in an unformatted partition (for GPT) is a little harder to look at and see what it does.  The install media boot suggestion was so you could then mount filesystems on the system of interest and get infomation. When running the boot-repair, it will offer to fix (don't yet) or just produce a report (and copy it to a place we can see it -- it's too big to include in your posting). Since there's only one legacy bootloader, why not just run grub-install from wherever you want it to be, so it shouldn't matter were it is now?

Comment: Did you click on the Boot-Repair link and read the instructions? Second box says create Boot-Info Summary which is a complete report on your system. And it will offer to upload it to a pastebin site so we can review it.

Comment: I am not aware of a link for boot repair.  Give me details like the context in which to find it.  Where is it?  I think I have a bootable grub repair USB stick around here but have not done anything with it.

Comment: @oldfred I think I'll go with your idea.  Among other things, I just had a thought that the default boot in GRUB is almost certainly on the disk that installed GRUB last.  I can test that idea fairly safely because this system has 3 focal installs, each of which can do this, and I can check that the results are as I expect before I do anything drastic like destroying a partition.

Comment: Link to Boot-Repair in comment above. Just click on it. Last installed version of grub is the one in control. I often had to edit /boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu/grub.cfg with correct UUID for main working install when doing another test install that I did not want as default boot.

Answer (score 0):

@ubfan1 Your second comment got me on the right track.  Thanks.  While most (not all) of my systems use GPT partitions, they mostly do not use EFI.  Mostly because they also boot Windows and when I was setting them up, I was having trouble mixing EFI with Windows, especially when there were multiple OS-es around.

Anyhow, your comment had me look in the running system at /boot/grub, not /boot/efi, and I found what partition it was on, which was the root partition of whatever image I booted.  Then it made sense to me that the default image would be the one that last installed GRUB, and would be the one that grub was currently using.

So the answer in my case is that GRUB is installed from the default image, and I can delete any other image without interfering with my ability to boot using that GRUB.  Problem solved.